# How to add library to spark shell

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, spark-shell

I have a library that I want to use in spark shell, how can I add this library to be accessible from the spark shell? 
sbt :

```
resolvers += Resolver.bintrayRepo("unsupervise", "maven")
libraryDependencies += "com.github.unsupervise" %% "spark-tss" % "0.1.1"
```

maven :

```
<dependencies>
<!-- Other Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.unsupervise</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-tss_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
<!-- Other Repositories ... -->
    <repository>
        <id>bintrayunsupervisemaven</id>
        <name>bintray-unsupervise-maven</name>
        <url>https://dl.bintray.com/unsupervise/maven/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `repositories` and `packages` parameters.

```
spark-shell \
  --repositories "https://dl.bintray.com/unsupervise/maven" \
  --packages "com.github.unsupervise:spark-tss_2.11:0.1.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have jars locally:

`./spark-shell --jars pathOfjarsWithCommaSeprated`

When the binary artifacts (jars) are managed through an artifact repository like Maven or Nexus then you would use artifact coordinates like *group id*, *artifact id* and *version*.

Reference: http//spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#using-the-shell

`./bin/spark-shell --master local[4] --packages "com.github.unsupervise:spark-tss_2.11:0.1.1"`

Comment: I don't have the jar, I only have these two instructors in maven or sbt.

Comment: Updated my answer